# Laravel on Postgre Ajax Request Returns url and null on Server?

Tags: jquery, ajax, laravel, request, get

I have a laravel project works just fine on my local (MacOs- Postgre). We just pulled the project on an Ubuntu server, but my ajax method is not working. It is expected to create a new selectbox with child elements on the database, Here is the Ajax method I use on frontend :

```
function selectChange(event) {
  getChilds($("#" + event.currentTarget.id + " option").filter(':selected').val(), event.currentTarget.id);
}

function getChilds(id) {

  $.ajax({
    type: 'GET',
    url: '{{ route('
    users.tickets.getChildsUserTicket ') }}',
    data: {
      id: id
    },
    datatype: "json",
    success: function(data) {
      if (data.firstSubs.length > 0) {
        selectCount++;
        clearSelects(id);

        var innerHtml = "<div class='dynamicSelect row birim_select" + selectCount + " form-group'>" +
          "<label for='example-text-input' class='col-md-4 col-form-label text-md-right'>" + selectCount + ". Kategori</label>" +
          "<div class='col-md-6'>" +
          "<select name='birim_id[]" + selectCount + "' id='birim_select" + selectCount + "' class='form-control birim_select' onChange='selectChange(event)'> " +
          "<option selected disabled>Seçim Yapınız</option>";

        data.firstSubs.forEach(val => {
          innerHtml += "<option value=" + val.id + "> " + val.name + "</option>"
        });

        innerHtml += "</select></div></div></div>";

        $('.selects').append(innerHtml)
      }
    },
    error: function(data) {
    }
  });
}
```

This is the backend controller :

```
    public function getFirstSubs(Request $request)
    {

        dd($request->all());
        $firstSubs = Department::where('isActive', 1)->where('parent_id', $request->id)->get();

        return response()->json(['firstSubs' => $firstSubs]);
    }
```

On the locale this is the response from dd() :
**"id" => "2"**

But on the server I get this response from same dd():
**"/users/tickets/getChilds" => null**

I have the same database and I checked routes they all seemed fine. Thank you in advance